# Access properties of an QtQuick / QML object after passing it to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

**STILL UNSOLVED** While the fix of my bug works for the Text item it does **NOT** work for the MouseArea. `console.log(key.keyMouseArea)` results in 'undefined'. But I can access it using `key.children[1]` !?!?!

**PARTLY SOLVED:** My fault, as `text` was a property of a child and I can access it using `key.textField.text`.

I pass an QtQuick object to a javascript function of another QtQuick object using the `this` pointer. In the called function I can see, in the log output, that the passing succeeded (VirtualKey_QMLTYPE_0(0x14a6bf0)). Now, I wish to access the properties of this object but the object is anonymous, or so. How can I convert or cast this parameter into its original type ?

Something like `Qt.castToQtQuickObject(pointer, VirtualKey)` or similar.

The available `createComponent` or `createObject` methods do not what I need as these create new instances.

Some file.qml:

```
Controller {
  id: controller
}

VirtualKey {
  Text { // didn't think of this child when asking ...
    id: textField
    text: "Hallo"
  }
  MouseArea {
    objectName: "mouse"
    id: keyMouseArea
  }
  Component.onCompleted: {
    controller.registerKey(this) // passing this instance of VirtualKey
  }

}
```

Controller.qml:

```
QtObject {
    function registerKey(key) {

        console.log("VKC: registering key " + key)

        // Output: VirtualKey_QMLTYPE_0(0x14a6bf0)

        console.log(key.textField) // works

        console.log(key.keyMouseArea) // undefined !!!

        console.log(key.children[1]) // works

        console.log(key.children[1].objectName) // -> "mouse"

    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Did you actually try to log `key.text`? If so, what is the output? From what I know QML&Javascript are very flexible on this matter and you should be able to get the value of the property

Comment: I wouldn't base on the JS _this_. Can you try to set `id` for the object and so pass it instead?

Comment: Thanks, will provide an example tomorrow if the problem persists. Logging key.txt prints 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had an property alias for the Text item in `VirtualKey`. That was the reason it worked for textField but not for keyMouseArea.

Adding `property alias keyMouseArea: keyMouseArea` in VirtualKey solved the issue for me. Now I can  use `key.keyMouseArea` to access also the MouseArea.